# How is the permutation matrix found in $A = P^tLU$ factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am learning how to factorize a matrix into the form $A = P^tLU$, and I am not understanding how the permutation matrix is obtained.

> A = $
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         0 & 0 & -1 & 1\\
>         1 & 1 & -1 & 2\\
>         -1 & -1 & 2 & 0\\
>         1 & 2 & 0 & 2
>         \end{bmatrix}
> $
>
> Row interchange $(E_1) \leftrightarrow (E_2)$, followed by $(E_3 + E_1) \rightarrow (E_3)$ and $(E_4 - E_1) \rightarrow (E_4)$ gives
>
> $
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         1 & 1 & -1 & 2\\
>         0 & 0 & -1 & 1\\
>         0 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
>         0 & 1 & 1 & 0
>         \end{bmatrix}
> $
>
> Row interchange $(E_2) \leftrightarrow (E_4)$, followed by $(E_4 + E_3) \rightarrow (E_4)$ gives
>
> U = $
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         1 & 1 & -1 & 2\\
>         0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
>         0 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
>         0 & 0 & 0 & 3
>         \end{bmatrix}
> $
>
> The permutation matrix associated with the row interchange $(E_1) \leftrightarrow (E_2)$ and $(E_2) \leftrightarrow (E_4)$ is
>
> P = $
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
>         0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
>         0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
>         1 & 0 & 0 & 0
>         \end{bmatrix}
> $

How is $P$ obtained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you must have written something wrong.

When you are permuting rows, that tells you what $P$ is.

You have, the permutation matrix associated with the row interchange $(E_1) \rightarrow (E_4)$ and $(E_2) \rightarrow (E_1)$ and $(E_4) \rightarrow (E_2)$. Row $E_3$ stayed put.

> P = $
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
>         0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
>         0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
>         1 & 0 & 0 & 0
>         \end{bmatrix}
> $

The way you would have come up with this permutation is by creating the augmented system using $A$, doing row eliminations, and swapping rows as the $P$ matrix says to get an upper triangular matrix.

Does that make sense? Take the matrix $A$, do Gaussian elimination on it and see how you would swap rows and you should get that P.

What you are actually doing is trying to write:

$$PAx = Pb.$$

Since $P^{-1} = P^{T}$, you end up with:

$$A = (P^T L) U$$

You show a $U$ above. If they gave you $A, P \text{and} U$, it is simple to find $L$.

However, you should be able to do this entire process just from $A$. If no $b$ is give, just skip that part of the problem and simply find $A = P^TLU$.

Comment: I corrected my typos.

Comment: Well done, and nicely explained! +1